# Using Json.stringify in controller in asp .net MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have written this part of ajax code to post some information that will be updated in the database.

```
function postUpdateList() {
    var id = $('#Id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: `Home/EditPost/${id}`,
        type:'POST',
        contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: JSON.stringify({ "Name": $('#name').val(), "Father": $('#father').val(), "Mother": $('#mother').val(), "Age": $('#age').val(), "Email": $('#email').val(), "Phone": $('#phone').val(), "Standard": $('#standard').val(), "Section": $('#section').val() }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Now how can I receive this Json.stringify object in my controller and update the information in the database?
This is my controller method:-

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditPost(int ID)
{ 
     var data = "Updated SUccesfully";
     return Json(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the same idea as others, you need to modify the POST action which is expected to receive the `ID` from the URL, and the `EditPostModel` object from the request body.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditPost(int ID, EditPostModel model)
{
    var data = "Updated SUccesfully";
    return Json(data);
}
```

```cs
public class EditPostModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Father { get; set; }
    public string Mother { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    // Following property
}
```

While there are some errors in the JavaScript part,

1. The `url` needs a leading slash.

   - Hence it will send the request to *`http://<your-domain>/Home/Post/{id}`*.
   - Without leading slash, the request will be sent to *`http://<your-domain>/Home/Post/{id}/Home/Post/{id}`* which is incorrect.
   - Reference: [What is the purpose of leading slash in HTML URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls#:%7E:text=That%27s%20a%20root%2Drelative%20link,the%20root%20of%20the%20site.&text=Another%20advantage%20is%20portability%20across%20domain%20changes.)
2. Use `data` to pass the data, not `dataType`. `dataType` specifies the form of data response returned from the server.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: `/Home/EditPost/${id}`,
    type:'POST',
    contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "Name": $('#name').val(), "Father": $('#father').val(), "Mother": $('#mother').val(), "Age": $('#age').val(), "Email": $('#email').val(), "Phone": $('#phone').val(), "Standard": $('#standard').val(), "Section": $('#section').val() }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

> Demo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what your controller receives with this request is a json object,

which represents a model. (Check your browsertools for the structure)

Therefore the best option would be to add `[FromBody] YourRequestModel model` as a paramter on your action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a special class for your data and use FromBody attribute in your controller action, also add ID attribute routing

```
[HttpPost("{ID}")]
public JsonResult EditPost(int ID, [FromBody] List<StudentModel>  data)
      return Json(data);
```